# Three.JS - Adjusting Bump Scale/Height - COLLADA

Tags: javascript, three.js, collada

Hello i am trying to adjust my bump map scale on my collada model.

Tried this but did not work:
[Three.js ColladaLoader bumpScale/weighting? Way to adjust bump map intensity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32224631/three-js-colladaloader-bumpscale-weighting-way-to-adjust-bump-map-intensity)

I am using r77
And this example: http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada
Replaced the current model with a more complex one that consist out of 3 meshes
Exported them all together in one .dae file. and they contain a couple of materials and textures
All textures are next to the .dae in the folder and working fine.
It is just the normal that is not working. and the alpha textures are bit odd.

I tried different things like so:

```
                    ------ none of these work ------
                    if ( child instanceof THREE.SkinnedMesh ) {
                    child.material.normalScale = (0.03,0.03); // adjusting bump height
                    // trying to change bump value.
                    //controlPanel.children[0].material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: controlPanel.children[0].material.map } );
                    //collada.scene.children[0].children[0].material.normalScale = (0.03,0.03);
                    //dae.children[2].material = new THREE. MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x333333, wireframe: true } )
                    //child.material.color.setRGB (1, 1, 0);
                    child.material.bumpScale = 0.03;
```

None of them seem to have effect on my model at all.
And i cannot find a good source that helps explaining the resons.
Hopefully someone here knows the problem!

Greets.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so with the help of guy named "bai"
I found out that blenders collada exporter
does not add the following inside the bump part of the .dae

```
          <bump bumptype="NORMALMAP">
```

instead it only does

```
          <bump>
```

which results in the normal map not working.